# A way to determine in which one of the boxes a number in Sudoku is

Tags: java, algorithm

I recently started implementing a Sudoku solver and it was done with the help of Algorithm X. This means that there is a cover matrix with lots of different possible solutions to a given Sudoku and it is algorithm's task to find the correct ones.

But the problem is in the generator of that matrix. I'll simplify the problem as much as possible. I am using a cover matrix which helps me solve Sudokus. Each line in that matrix is a unique entry. In order to compose a single line, we need to determine in which cell, row, column and box a given number in Sudoku is.

Since Sudoku dimensions are defined by the dimensions of the inner boxes (image below), I'm using those dimensions to determine in which row and column a pregiven number is.

Every box has a dimension of width and height or if you prefer m and n or any other notation - classic 9x9 Sudoku has a m = 3 and n = 3 (the dimension of inner box).

[image: one of sudoku boxes]

As you can see this is a custom sudoku with dimensions m = 2 and n = 3 and it has 6 boxes.

I am having a problem with creating a formula that would give me the information in which box a number is. So basically input should be the position (index) of the number in the Sudoku and the output the number of the box in which that number is.

Below is the code i tried polishing so far but it still doesn't calculate the indexes quite correctly. I used the index of the row in which the given number is and tried using that to determine index of the column and tried combining the two to determine the number of the box. Feel free to tell me where i am making a mistake.

```
     public static void assignSudokuBox(int rowIndex, int m, int n){

     double x = Math.ceil(Math.ceil((rowIndex+1)*1.0/(m*n))/m);

     double columnIndex = (rowIndex%(m*n))*m*n + (rowIndex/(m*n));

     double y = Math.ceil(Math.ceil(columnIndex*1.0/(m*n))/n);

     double number = Math.ceil((x-1)*m+y);

     System.out.println("Box of index " + rowIndex + " is: " + number + ".");

 }
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what the method should do. Please provide some example input and expected output.

Comment: @Manu Ignore my method because it doesn't fully work. Example of a working method should be for example: assignSudokuBox(10, 2, 3) for upper sudoku should return 2 because it is in the second box (or 1, depends on your box enumeration). And so on, for example assignSudokuBox(16, 2, 3) should return 4 because it is in the fourth box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 0-based indices and boxes numbered in the same fassion as the cells, you can calculate the value as follows:

```
public static void assignSudokuBox(int rowIndex, int m, int n) {
    // index, if devided to pieces n x 1
    int nChunkIndex = rowIndex / n;

    // every row has m of those pieces and there are m rows in each box
    int row = nChunkIndex / (m*m);

    int column = nChunkIndex % m;

    int result = column + row * m;

    System.out.println("Box of index " + rowIndex + " is: " + result + ".");

}
```

Output for

```
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    assignSudokuBox(i, 2, 3);
}
```

```
Box of index 0 is: 0.
Box of index 1 is: 0.
Box of index 2 is: 0.
Box of index 3 is: 1.
Box of index 4 is: 1.
Box of index 5 is: 1.
Box of index 6 is: 0.
Box of index 7 is: 0.
Box of index 8 is: 0.
Box of index 9 is: 1.
Box of index 10 is: 1.
Box of index 11 is: 1.
Box of index 12 is: 2.
Box of index 13 is: 2.
Box of index 14 is: 2.
Box of index 15 is: 3.
Box of index 16 is: 3.
Box of index 17 is: 3.
Box of index 18 is: 2.
Box of index 19 is: 2.
Box of index 20 is: 2.
Box of index 21 is: 3.
Box of index 22 is: 3.
Box of index 23 is: 3.
Box of index 24 is: 4.
Box of index 25 is: 4.
Box of index 26 is: 4.
Box of index 27 is: 5.
Box of index 28 is: 5.
Box of index 29 is: 5.
Box of index 30 is: 4.
Box of index 31 is: 4.
Box of index 32 is: 4.
Box of index 33 is: 5.
Box of index 34 is: 5.
Box of index 35 is: 5.
```

Answer (score 2):

Say p is your number in the grid. Then:

```
int box_w = ((p-1)/n)%m;
int box_h = (p-1)/(n*m*m);
int box_number = box_w + m*box_h + 1;  // box_number is the value you want
```